# Slow gtkmm compile for tiny program

Tags: g++, gtk, gtkmm

I am learning gtkmm and extremely simple sample projects (i.e. a window with a  button that opens a dialog box) are taking ~3 seconds to compile with g++ on reasonable hardware.

```
$ time g++ examplewindow.cpp main.cpp `pkg-config   gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs` 

real    0m4.011s
user    0m3.630s
sys 0m0.374s
```

Is there anything I can do to cut down this time?

I am on Linux using gtkmm version `3.24.0-2` and version `8.3.0` of g++.

---

Edit: Code

**examplewindow.h**

```
#pragma once                                                                    
                                                                                
#include <gtkmm/window.h>                                                       
#include <gtkmm/buttonbox.h>                                                    
#include <gtkmm/button.h>                                                       
                                                                                
class ExampleWindow : public Gtk::Window {                                      
                                                                                
public:                                                                         
    ExampleWindow();                                                            
    virtual ~ExampleWindow();                                                   
                                                                                
protected:                                                                      
    void on_button_info_clicked();                                              
    void on_button_question_clicked();                                          
                                                                                
    Gtk::ButtonBox m_ButtonBox;                                                 
    Gtk::Button m_Button_Info, m_Button_Question;                               
};
```

**examplewindow.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>                                                             
#include <gtkmm/messagedialog.h>                                                
                                                                                
#include "examplewindow.h"                                                      
                                                                             
ExampleWindow::ExampleWindow()                                                  
    :m_ButtonBox( Gtk::ORIENTATION_VERTICAL ),                                  
    m_Button_Info( "Show info box" ),                                           
    m_Button_Question( "Show question box" )                                    
{                                                                               
    add( m_ButtonBox );                                                         
                                                                                
    m_Button_Info.signal_clicked().connect( sigc::mem_fun( *this, &ExampleWindow::on_button_info_clicked) );
    m_Button_Question.signal_clicked().connect( sigc::mem_fun( *this, &ExampleWindow::on_button_question_clicked) );
                                                                             
    m_ButtonBox.pack_start( m_Button_Info );                                    
    m_ButtonBox.pack_start( m_Button_Question );                                
                                                                                
    show_all_children();                                                        
}                                                                               
                                                                                
ExampleWindow::~ExampleWindow() {                                               
}                                                                               
                                                                                
void ExampleWindow::on_button_info_clicked() {                                  
    Gtk::MessageDialog dialog( *this, "This is an INFO MessageDialog", false, Gtk::MESSAGE_QUESTION, Gtk::BUTTONS_OK_CANCEL);
                                                                              
    dialog.set_secondary_text( "This is the secondary text" );                  
                                                                                
    dialog.run();                                                               
}                                                                               
                                                                                
void ExampleWindow::on_button_question_clicked() {                              
    Gtk::MessageDialog dialog( *this, "This is a QUESTION MessageDialog", false, Gtk::MESSAGE_QUESTION, Gtk::BUTTONS_OK_CANCEL);
                                                                             
    dialog.set_secondary_text( "This is the other text" );                      
                                                                                
    int result = dialog.run();                                                  
                                                                                
    switch( result ) {                                                          
        case( Gtk::RESPONSE_OK ):                                               
            std::cout << "Ok clicked" << std::endl;                             
            break;                                                              
        case( Gtk::RESPONSE_CANCEL ):                                           
            std::cout << "Cancel clicked" << std::endl;                         
            break;                                                              
        default:                                                                
            std::cout << "Unexpected button clicked" << std::endl;              
            break;                                                              
    }                                                                           
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <gtkmm/application.h>                                                  
                                                                                
#include "examplewindow.h"                                                      
                                                                                
int main( int argc, char **argv ) {                                             
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create( argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.example" );  
                                                                                
    ExampleWindow window;                                                       
                                                                                
    return app->run( window );                                                  
}
```

Comment: Could you please add the code?

Comment: @BobMorane Added. When doing so I noticed that there was an include of `gtkmm.h`. Replacing this with the specific includes has taken a second off the compile time, so it is around 3 seconds now. Compared to my experience with C,  this still seems like a long time for such a small project but maybe this is just to be expected for C++ and gtkmm. If the answer to this question is just "that's normal" I would appreciate just being told that too.

Comment: It's normal. First of all: never include single headers, especially ones that are generated, like the C++ bindings. Additionally: C++ compilation times are slow for a variety of factors. You could look into unity builds to shave down the build time: https://mesonbuild.com/Unity-builds.html

Comment: @ebassi I've just found out about the `-E -P` flags to gcc which let you view the code after preprocessing. For one C project I have the code is 800 lines after the preprocessor. For this project the code is 253,867 lines. I guess that explains the problem and it's just something I'll have to get used to.